# FileNotFoundError Python Script

Tags: python, path, file-not-found

I am trying to run a python script, .py in the windows command prompt.

I drag the script from my files into the command prompt window. I run it.
Then, the script presents a prompt for me to enter the file I would like to parse. I am supposed to enter a file like this: *filename.txt*

When I go to do this, I get the FileNotFoundError. They are both located in my downloads folder. Any ideas as to why? I've tried a couple of things but having no luck.

The script must be performed this way because this is a script many people will use and it is likely that they will receive it and download it and the file to parse to their computer so it'll be located in their downloads folder.

When I created the script I did it in Notepad++ and had a separate folder where I put the file and script and it worked fine this way. I am just ensuring it works from the perspective of someone who's downloading it off an email or website, etc.

Thanks !

Comment: What is the working directory? You can Shift-Right-Click on the downloads directory and say "open command prompt here", which will give you the correct working directory.

Comment: When you try to `open` a file with a relative pathname, like  `filename.txt`, that’s relative to the current working directory (so if your command prompt says, e.g., `D:\Spam\>`, you’re trying to open a file `D:\Spam\filename.txt`), not relative to the path to the script, or anything else.

Comment: If the script only uses a relative path to the file then the script will have to be run in the same directory as the target file

Comment: If you drag and drop the file you want to work on to the command prompt, the same way you did with the script, it should give you the full absolute path instead of just the name, and things will work. If, on the other hand, you want to type in names, you probably want to `cd` to the directory the files are in, so you can just type the file name without the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that happened to me a lot.

To solve it just write the whole directory of the file.

If you are in windows

```
c:\user\username\Desktop\file.txt
```

If you are in linux or mac:

```
/home/username/Desktop/file.txt
```

Comment: Lol it worked, I had I tried this before, but I guess the first time I added quotes to the file path, thank you !

Comment: Camille: As @abarnert said in a comment under your question, you can also drag the input file onto the prompt when your script prompts for it, which should enter the full path to the dragged file there instead of requiring the user to type the whole thing in manually. It's also less error-prone.

Comment: So to make this more user friendly, I did not want to make the user enter the entire path. So I did the following code:  userpath = os.getcwd()
fullpath = os.path.join(userpath, var), where var is the filename I ask of the user. When I do this I get the same error but its because the filepath has double backslashes (C:\\Users\\....). I know why they're there. But how do I get rid of them?

Comment: @ZiadAbouelfarah, this dragging of the input does not work in my case, I still get a file not found error, the file path is then shown in the error message with double backslashes

Comment: Dont drag it Just Put the path file if you drage it is like you saying you want to open the file from the cmd