# Specified file not found '''FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory''':

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this chatbot called Albert and ran into this problem while i was debugging it and I didn't know how to solve my problem.since I am newbie.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

I tried double back slashes for overcoming the unicode error

'''

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Albin Johns\\PROJECT 
MATRIX\\Database\\RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe), 
buffering=1000) as f:
```

'''

Please do let me know if u require more than the given code to solve this problem

Comment: print the string you generate in the `open` statement. Does that file exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundError Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900640/filenotfounderror-python-script)

Comment: could anyone explain in a bit more detail....i am a newbie.....yes the file exists

Comment: Your format taking 2 params, but your string only has 1 param to replace. Can you provide full file name and value of timeframe?

Comment: You say the file exists. I know you think it does but there may be an error in the filename. Print out the filename from your program, and then go the folder where you think the file of that name is, and paste `dir` followed by the filename to the Windows console, and see if the OS agrees with you.

Comment: "I tried double back slashes for overcoming the unicode error" What unicode error?

Answer (score 0):

Do not combine everything at one statement like that, please try to split it to some smaller statements. It will help you a lot when you need to trace the problem

Try this:

```
fileDir = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Albin Johns\\PROJECT 
MATRIX\\Database\\RC_"

filename = format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe)
#print to make sure filename is correct
print(filename)

filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, 'filename')

with open(filepath, buffering=1000) as f:
```